# Count files recursively without counting subfolders

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of folders that all have two subfolders, and these two subfolders each have one subfolder. I have already written a script that sorts images into these folders based on filename, and I have found a code snippet which can generate a list of each directory and the count of how many items are in there. The thing is that I would like the recursive search to not count the subfolders as a file, while still searching through them. The code I am using at the moment is the following:

```
#set-location "MyDirectory"
dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName
(dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

This gives me a list in the following way with directory and count:

```
C:\...\Folder1 2 #These are the two subfolders that are listed
C:\...\Folder1.1 18 #These are the files in the folder, the subfolder included
C:\...\Folder1.2 47 #Subfolder included
C:\...\Folder1.1.1 10 #Herein lies only files
C:\...\Folder1.2.1 5 #Only files
```

Basically, I want the count of Folder1.1 and Folder1.2 to not contain Folder 1.1.1 and Folder1.2.1 as they are folders and not files.

My efforts so far have resulted in either only searching for files or only for folders.

Comment: In PowerShell3  or newer simply use `-Directory` parameter in the first `dir` and `-File` in the 2nd `dir`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are so close:

```
dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName
(dir $_.FullName -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | Measure-Object).Count }
```

or

```
dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName
(dir $_.FullName -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } ).Count }
```

just counting the FileInfo items.

And just do me a favor and use "Get-ChildItem" instead of "dir". it is the same but it looks so cmd like.
Dir /r --> I understand
Get-ChildItem -Recurse --> super
Dir -Recurse --s is like a creepy hybrid.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Though the second -recurse is not needed in my case as I am not interested in the total count in the top folder.

Can you elaborate on your comment about dir and Get-ChildItem and the creepy hybrid thing. What do you mean?

Comment: Just "dir" is a old cmd syntax.
in Powershell "dir" is a alias of "Get-childItem". My Powershell loving brain can't handel cmd syntax mixed with Powershell. But it will work like a charm.

Comment: If this answer is correct, please accept as the solution.

Comment: Oh I see. Well dir does make the code shorter, even if not as pretty I guess! Have accepted your solution. Thanks!